# Modifying existing windows context for ".img"

Tags: windows, registry

I want to construct a .reg file to add contexts for .img extension bound to my application.
Here is my registry file...

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.img]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.img\shell]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.img\shell\myprogram]
@="View Info (My Program)"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.img\shell\myprogram\command]
@="myprogram.exe d \"%1\""
```

This was suppose to add "View Info (My Program)" context whenever I right click on .img file. But it's not working, it seems like the default extensions (like .iso .png .jpg) such stuff doesn't work.

Is there any workaround for this! Happy to hear it from you :)

Comment: What's output from `assoc .img`? It's `Windows.IsoFile` for me. Then, all the above stuff belongs to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Windows.IsoFile` instead of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.img`.

Comment: In any case, read https://fileinfo.com/extension/img - `.img` has no  relationship with _pictures_  like `.png`, `.jpg` etc.

Comment: Iso path works as per JosefZ response! but PNG and JPG no clue!